# Trying to retrieve field from one collection based on UID of two collections matching

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve the name of each student where their userUID matches up from the attendance collection and the student collection i.e if the two user UID's match I would like to return the name associated with the userUID from the student collection. I am querying the attendance table to begin.

Here is my code:

```
public void viewAttendance(View v) {
    attendanceRef2.orderBy("sessionID", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
            .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            String data = "";

            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                Attendance attendance = documentSnapshot.toObject(Attendance.class);
                Student studentName = documentSnapshot.toObject(Student.class);

                String sessionID = attendance.getSessionID();
                String studentID = attendance.getUserUID();
                String attendanceUID = studentName.getUserUID();
                String name;

                if (studentID.equals(attendanceUID)){

        name = studentName.getName();
                    data+= "Session ID: " + sessionID + "\n" + "Student Name: " + name + "\n\n";
                }
            }
            textViewData.setText(data);
        }
    });
}
```

EDITED CODE

```
public void viewAttendance(View v) {
    attendanceRef2.orderBy("sessionID", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
            .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            String data = "";

            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                Attendance attendance = documentSnapshot.toObject(Attendance.class);
                Student studentName = documentSnapshot.toObject(Student.class);

                String sessionID = attendance.getSessionID();
                String attendanceUID = attendance.getUserUID();
                String studentUID = studentName.getUserUID();
                final String name = "";

                if (attendanceUID.equals(studentUID)){
                    db.collection("Student").document("name").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                            textViewData.setText(name);
                        }
                    });

                }
                data+= "Session ID: " + sessionID + "\n" + "Student Name: " + name + "\n\n";
            }
            textViewData.setText(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is currently retrieving the session ID although returning null in the student name

Comment: You're loading a single document from a single collection in the code your now have. If you want to load the student from a different collection, you will have to do so inside the loop with another `get()` like: `db.collection("Users").document(studentID).get().addOnCompleteListener(...`.

Comment: This is where I have added your suggestions. It retrieves the sessionID then disappears showning nothing?

Comment: You will need an `onSuccess`, just you like have for your outer listener. And then *inside that new* `onSuccess` you load the user information from the new document that you loaded with `Student studentName = documentSnapshot.toObject(Student.class);`

Comment: so I would have to insert this in the for loop or just before beside the query

Answer (score 0):

You're getting closer. You need to load two documents:

1. The attendance information
2. The user information for the student

Since the user name comes from the second document, you can only call `DocumentSnapshot.toObject` once that second document has been loaded (so in the `onComplete` or `onSuccess` callback of the second listener). Something like:

```
public void viewAttendance(View v) {
  attendanceRef2.orderBy("sessionID", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
        .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
        String data = "";

        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            Attendance attendance = documentSnapshot.toObject(Attendance.class);

            String sessionID = attendance.getSessionID();
            String attendanceUID = attendance.getUserUID();
            String studentUID = studentName.getUserUID();

            if (attendanceUID.equals(studentUID)){
                db.collection("Student").document(studentUID).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        Student studentName = task.getResult().toObject(Student.class);
                        textViewData.setText(studentName);
                        // Or maybe: textViewData.setText(studentName.getName());

                        data+= "Session ID: " + sessionID + "\n" + "Student Name: " + studentName + "\n\n";
                        textViewData.setText(data);
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: The name variable when trying to print out the data is confusing me Frank, after the if statement finishes how does it fetch the name based on the userUID's.

Comment: Aha... I has missed those lines. Since they need the name (which is only available after the second document has also loaded), they need to be *inside* the second callback. I updated my answer.

Comment: with this updated solution I am getting a runtime error in the logcat, it is pointing to this line textViewData.setText(studentName);

Comment: it says attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Comment: when I search the student collection then use .document("name") is this implying that name is a document. Because I am looking for the name of the students which is a field within a document held in the student collection

Comment: There's really a bit much going on here, making it hard to help in one go. I guess the documents in your `Student` collection use the UID as their key then (which is what my original comment to your question mentioned)? I updated the code to reflect that.

Comment: Sorry maybe I haven't been very clear, what I am trying to achieve is this, if the attendanceUID field in the attendance document matches the studentUID field in the student document, I want to retrieve the name field from the student document